# How to display a multi layer JSON in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I have this JSON response:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderId": "4123456789",
      "dateTimeOrderPlaced": "2017-02-09T12:39:48+01:00",
      "orderItems": [
        {
          "orderItemId": "2012345678",
          "ean": "0000007740404",
          "cancelRequest": false,
          "quantity": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I passed it in my view with the `.json()` method. I use this in my template:

```html
{% for key, value in orders.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this in my HTML:

```html
orders: [{'orderId': '2529081520', 'dateTimeOrderPlaced': '2019-09-07T00:12:16+02:00', 'orderItems': [{'orderItemId': '2298728074', 'ean': '8945005881389', 'cancelRequest': False, 'quantity': 1}]}]
```

But how to dissect it further? For example to get the `OrderId` or the `ean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access dictionary items with the template variable dot-notation, like this

```
{% for order in orders.orders %}
    {{ order.orderId }}
    {% for item in order.orderItems %}
    {{ item.ean }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming the context variable `orders` contains your parsed JSON, this template would be rendered like this:

```
OrderId: 4123456789

EAN: 0000007740404
```